# renewcommand ignored in caption

Tags: captions, renewcommand

I have redefined a command to give me a negative sign that is more convenient for me.  This works in all contexts *except* within a caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}                                                            
                                                                                
\renewcommand{\-}{\raisebox{.8mm}{\text{\tiny\boldmath$-$}}}
\newcommand{\negative}{\raisebox{.8mm}{\text{\tiny\boldmath$-$}}}

\begin{document}
Some text using the new commands: $1\-2~3\negative4$.

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Caption text using the new commands: $1\-2~3\negative4$.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get the command I desire to work within a caption?

Comment: unrelated but are you sure you want to do `\renewcommand{\-}` if you know your document is only used by you it's sort of OK but you can't really use a fragment relying on that definition in any conference proceedings or journal submission or with standard bibliography databases. It's overwritting the standard latex command to mark a hyphenation point.

Comment: the problem is not the caption but the figure environment. `\-` is overwritten/restored in various places (in a \parbox your definition wouldn't work either) and imho you should better not do that.

Comment: Yes. I read that \- is used to specify an optional hyphen (I assume such a hyphen would be used only if the line wraps at that point in the word). I didn't realize that it was as essential as you folks say it is (I've already used this in two publications).  I suppose I will have to find another shorthand.  Thanks for the advice.